# What is the difference in creating objects in Java by these two ways?

Tags: java

```
StackOfStrings s;
s = new StackOfStrings(100);
```

and this

```
StackOfStrings s = new StackOfStrings(100);
```

Comment: Short answer: Nothing.

Comment: The both are the same thing

Comment: This may help -  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2029531/4121347

Comment: One character and a new line :P

Comment: thanks for minuses and answers.

Comment: *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla not quite - there's two characters + newline

Comment: @Holloway oops, u got it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Short answer

Nothing.

#### Longer answer

1<sup>st</sup> bytecode generated for the first one [1]:

```
class Test {
  Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Test
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method "<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: return
}
```

2<sup>nd</sup> one: See [1].

Comment: there is 2nd bitcode missing? Also... you wanted to add some links at [1]??

Comment: @JordiCastilla The second bytecode is referring to the first one - they're exactly the same. Reference: `javap -c <class>`. The `[1]` and `[2]` are placeholders of mine.

Comment: @JordiCastilla He wants to say that both are the same, as they produce the same byte code.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks!! 

Answer (score 0):

No difference in the way you are *creating* them. Only difference is that in the first example you are first *declaring* the variable *s* to be of type `StackOfStrings`. This means you have not yet decided what actual type of object you will create (could be a subtype of `StackOfStrings`) Try reading this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, when you do this `StackOfStrings s;` you are not creating an object, just a reference. When you do this `s = new StackOfStrings(100);` you are linking the reference memory tho the new object that you created. So, when you this `StackOfStrings s = new StackOfStrings(100);`  you are just doing the both things at the same time.
So, why don't just do the second way? When you don't know if you are receive an object or create a new one. For instance:

```
Object o;
if (condition) {
  o = getSomeObject();
} else {
  o = new Object()
}
```